# How can i load a file for multiple methods to access?

Tags: java, file, io

I'd like to load and read a text file inside an interface. I can load it within one method inside a list:

```
 static List readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List result;
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            result = (List) lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return result;

    }
```

But I want to use this result (list) inside other methods I have in my interface like `nextItem()` and `boolean hasMoreItems()`.
How can I load my file so that the other methods can see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by calling the read method straight into the ArrayList:

```
public final ArrayList<String> file = readLines(); // Stores read config file
ListIterator<String> list = file.listIterator(); // Iterates through stored config file

public ArrayList<String> readLines() { // Reads config file

    try {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(
                Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("configFile.txt")));

        return lines;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now the other methods in this class can access this ArrayList!